# Firefox bug? Changing an option field via javascript doesn't update the validity status of an element

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox

So I ran across this issue with firefox, and I'm wondering if it's a bug or if the standard is just ambiguous or something? It seems like firefox isn't updating its internal state from

```
$('#form').is(function(){ return this.checkValidity();}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DxWUs/

In chrome, it returns "false true true", but in firefox it's "false false true".